# Storing sql results to an single dimension array in php

Tags: php, sql, arrays

i'm doing my project, i don't know how to store my sql query results into a single dimension array. I do know how to store it in a two dimensional array im using this line of code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        extract($row);
        $list[] = array('trans_id' => $trans_id, 'room_id' => $room_id, 'date_in' => $date_in, 'time_in' => $time_in,'date_out' => $date_out,'time_out' => $time_out, 'fname' => $fname, 'mname' => $mname, 'lname' => $lname, 'address' => $address, 'mphone' => $mphone, 'hphone' => $hphone, 'email_add' => $email_add); 
    }
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? You have only one result - $list has only one nested array?

Comment: i want trans_id in index0, and so on.

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking please elaborate with examples how do you want your results to be.

Comment: i want my results to in a single dimension array. i want the results to look like $list[0] = trans_id ....

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what you are looking for, but I try to narrow it down:

```
// you'll get just one result...
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    extract($row);
    $list[] = array('trans_id' => $trans_id, 'room_id' => $room_id, ...); 
}
// get the first...
current($list);

// or even simpler
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    extract($row);
    // just one result...
    $list = array('trans_id' => $trans_id, 'room_id' => $room_id, ...); 
}


// and in case you want to collect the results inside an associative array....
$list = array('trans_id' => array(), 'room_id' => array(), ...);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    foreach( $row as $key => $value ) {
        $list[ $key ][] = $value;
    }
}
```